# How to register a TImpl that has one moregeneric type parameter than TService in SimpleInjector?

Tags: generics, dependency-injection, registration, simple-injector

I am doing the following right now

```
container.Register<IDatabaseMapper<User>, DatabaseMapper<User, OracleException>>();
container.Register<IDatabaseMapper<Desk>, DatabaseMapper<Desk, OracleException>>();
container.Register<IDatabaseMapper<Commodity>, DatabaseMapper<Commodity, OracleException>>();
```

But i would like to do something like this

```
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IDatabaseMapper<>), typeof(DatabaseMapper<,OracleException>));
```

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this possible? Yes and no :-)

`typeof(DatabaseMapper<,OracleException>)` is not valid C# code. You either have to supply **all** generic type arguments or none at all. So there is no way to inform the `Container` that it should fill in the missing `TException` type argument with a `OracleException`. So no, you can't do this.

But yes, of course you can do this :-). Simply create a `OracleExceptionDatabaseMapper<T>` class that inherits from `DatabaseMapper<T, OracleException>` and use that type in the registration:

```cs
// Helper class
public class OracleExceptionDatabaseMapper<T>
    : DatabaseMapper<T, OracleException>
{
}

// Registration
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IDatabaseMapper<>),
    typeof(OracleExceptionDatabaseMapper<>));
```

This way the given implementation has only 1 generic type and that can be mapped to the single generic type argument of the given service interface.

**UPDATE**

Since Simple Injector 2.4 it is possible to register parial open generic types, but since this is still not supported by C# you will have to create the partial open generic type by hand as follows:

```cs
Type databaseMapperType = typeof(DatabaseMapper<,>).MakeGenericType(
    typeof(DatabaseMapper<,>).GetGenericArguments().First(),
    typeof(OracleException));

container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IDatabaseMapper<>), databaseMapperType);
```

Comment: `typeof(DatabaseMapper<,OracleException>)`
did not indicate any error at compile time so i wrongly assumed that it should work. Your approach works but that is exactly what i wanted to avoid - creating a class for a database vendor specific exception instead of providing the type as a a parameter

Comment: like this `DatabaseMapper<TEntity, TException> : IDatabaseMapper<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class, IEntity
        where TException : DbException`

Comment: Creating an extra class is usually not a problem, expecially when you put that class close to the configuration of the container. In that case it is invisible to the application and simply part of your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx). Reconsider taking this solution over the more complex (but fun) `ResolveUnregisteredType`.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here is an example of how to do this using unregistered type resolution:

```cs
container.ResolveUnregisteredType += (s, e) =>
{
    var serviceType = e.UnregisteredServiceType;

    if (serviceType.IsGenericType &&
        serviceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDatabaseMapper<>))
    {
        Type argument = serviceType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

        var closedDatabaseMapperType = typeof(DatabaseMapper<,>)
            .MakeGenericType(argument, typeof(OracleException));

        var registration =
            container.GetRegistration(closedDatabaseMapperType, true);

        e.Register(registration.BuildExpression());
    }
};
```

The `ResolveUnregisteredType` event will be called by the container whenever a type is requested that is not registered. This gives you a last chance to register that type. The supplied `UnregisteredTypeEventArgs` contains two `Register` method overloads that allow you to register that type (using either a `Func<T>` or using an `Expression`).

The code above checks to see if the requested service type is an `IDatabaseMapper<T>` and if so, it will construct a `DatabaseMapper<T, OracleExpression>` where `T` is replaced with the actual type of the service type. Using that type a registration for that type is requested from the container. Using the `BuildExpression` method of that registration object, we can build an expression tree that describes the creation of a new instance of that `DatabaseMapper`. This expression id than registered using the `e.Register` method, which effectively maps the `IDatabaseMapper<T>` to the creation of a `DatabaseMapper<T, OracleException>`.

IMPORTANT: I believe that using unregistered type resolution should only be used as fallback option, since there are often easier ways to solve your problem (such as the one I shown in my other answer), but unregistered type resolution can be useful in certain advanced scenarios (when the `DatabaseMapper<T, TException>` is sealed for instance).